# Abstract with Inaccessible due to its protection

Tags: c#

This is my class stock  all my attributes in the stock class have to be protected other attributes and methods are public.

My problem is in the Book class which inherits from the Stock Class

```
abstract public class Stock
{
    protected int libraryNum;
    protected string title;
    protected Member member;
    protected DateTime returnDate;
    private int id;
    private string strtitle;

    public Stock(int id, string strtitle)
    {
        libraryNum = id;
        title = strtitle;
        returnDate = DateTime.Now;
        member = null;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString();
    }
}

public class Journal :Stock
{
    private int vol;

    public Journal(int vol, string strtitle, int id) : base(id, strtitle)
    {
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString();
    }

}
```

Down here I get a squiggle red line under the id in the Base(id, Strtitle) 
it says inaccessible due to its protection level. 
I am not sure how to make it accessible.

```
public class Book : Stock
{
    private string authour;

    public Book(string strtitle, string strauthor, int intid) : base(id, strtitle)
    {
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you attempt to create an instance of an object that implements an abstract class or interface, the object must have the same level of access.

Comment: I would consider adopting a coding style for member variables such that you can differentiate them from method arguments or other scoped variables.

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant to pass `intid` instead of `id` which is indeed `private` to the (parent) `Stock` class.

Try this:

```
public Book(string strtitle, string strauthor, int intid) : base(intid, strtitle)
```

Comment: I don't have the issue in the Public class Journal with base:(id,strtitle)

Comment: @RandomUsers, because the constructor of `Journal` *does* declare a parameter named `id`, it then passes its value to the base constructor.

Comment: Because in Journal you called the parameter "id" where as in Book you called the parameter "intid".  You should probably standardize all the names, and I'd suggest following the [.NET Framework Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I just discovered that when I looked at it , it was the typo

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
abstract public class Stock
```

To:

```
public abstract class Stock
```

Also:

You are calling the base class constructor and attempting to pass in variable id but you are passing in intid. id is a field of the abstract class Stock, where as intid is the parameter.  You are telling the implementing class to call it's base class with a field value that already belongs to the base class.  The id is private so it isn't seen by the implementing class.

Comment: The order of modifiers doesn't matter in C#.

Comment: I realize that.  Sorry, I wasn't done putting together my response.  Merely mentioning the order of modifiers for consistency considering that the rest of the application follows a different pattern.